# How far back in time do RPC nodes retain transaction history?

Tags: signature, historical-data

What's the average an RPC would keep all signatures for an Account stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public nodes at `api.mainnet-beta.solana.com` are connected to longterm transaction history storage with BigTable, so you can use those RPC nodes to get full transaction history.

Beware that they have strict rate limits, so be sure to respect any 429s returned!

Comment: Good to know! I will probably keep using this for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://bpf.wtf/sol-state-history/)

> /// Returns the state of an account just before a given tx. fn
> get_historical_account_info(Address, Signature) -> AccountInfo
>
> As of now, no service provides this simple query. Let's explore the
> technical background of why state history is notoriously hard. We also
> propose a practical design for implementing a state history archive.

the above article explains why. That data must live on RPC server for a short amount of time and then it gets deleted.

But as far as I know, Genesysgo which is the RPC service provider in the Solana network solving this accounts storage problem. From [here](https://genesysgo.medium.com/the-shadow-drive-decentralized-storage-optimized-for-solana-11f2f257aaf2)

> Now, just because historical transactions are irrelevant to the
> current “in the moment” state of all accounts on Solana …again,
> because every event leading up to the present had to be passed through
> the Solana validator network and therefore was part of the consensus
> that led to the current state… doesn’t mean that historical
> transactions aren’t important to the developers and users performing
> actions on Solana.
>
> This is where we circle back to Shadow Drive. The Shadow Drive
> utilizes the world’s most performant state machine to ensure the
> validity and integrity of the state of its storage network via
> on-chain change events.

Comment: Yeah I figure Solana itself doesnt care about history just current state.I was using the GenesysGO RPC which claimed to have all historical data but they shut it down because of cost and them moving on full time to work on other things like shadow drive. I guess best bet is to find a service and pay for historical data.